# HTTP Conditional GET not working

Tags: http, browser-cache

I am slightly confused as what should be the actual behavior given a GET request with below signature.

**Request URL**: https://some-web-server/assets/views/header.html
The response come fine with 200 status code with below response headers

**Response Headers:**

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600  
Cache-Control: no-cache  
Connection: Keep-Alive  
Content-Encoding: gzip  
Content-Length: 1312  
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8  
Date: Thu, 05 Apr 2018 18:44:56 GMT  
ETag: 2f7b535ad0a129b93a432f997b09785e  
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT  
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100  
Last-Modified: Sat, 31 Mar 2018 11:07:28 GMT  
Server: Apache/2.4.28 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j  
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

I understand that in response Cache-Control Header is set to no-cache, so next time when I hit the same request then the server is expected to send 304 instead of 200 with full body as content has not change on the server
But the response is always 200 OK

**Request Headers**:

```
GET /assets/views/header.html HTTP/1.1  
Host: some-web-server  
Connection: keep-alive  
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*  
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br  
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9  
If-None-Match:    2f7b535ad0a129b93a432f997b09785e  
If-Modified-Since: Sat, 31 Mar 2018 11:07:28 GMT
```

Can some one please help if I am missing something obvious. Or the webserver might not have support for conditional GET.
I am using Play framework 2.x version with Apache as reverse proxy in between.

Comment: That might be an effect of using the XHR API. It doesn't necessarily mean that 200 was really sent.

Unrelated to that: the syntax of the Etag is invalid.

Comment: Are you suggesting that browser(chrome in my case) would ignore xhr requests for caching?

Comment: No, I'm saying that XHR might return a 200 status although the actual HTTP response was a 304.